# Saxon Genitive in Naming Conventions?

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

What do you call your functions when names that contain a saxon genitive like "Verify Task's Priority" and "Change Argument's Priority" or "Increase Action's Delay"?

Do you drop the apostrophe? `verifyTasksPriority(), changeArgumentsPriority(), increaseActionsDelay()`

Do you drop both the apostrophe and the "s"? `verifyTaskPriority(), changeArgumentPriority(), increaseActionDelay()`

Do you replace the saxon genitive with "of"? `verifyPriorityOfTask(), changePriorityOfArgument(), increaseDelayOfAction()`?

I don't like the first option because it sounds like the function works on multiple things rather than just one thing.
I don't like the second option because it doesn't sound natural. I don't like the third option because the word, *of*, in a function name just doesn't sound right.

What option do you use?

Comment: So it's option 2 then. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the second.  It sounds good to me.  Think of "Task Priority" as a compound word like "vacuum cleaner".

Comment: This is exactly my view too. Compound nouns are usually the most succinct way to name functions.

Answer (score 4):

I find that numbers two and three sound fine to me, and are descriptive.  I use the second option.  The first option could possibly be confusing since it seems to indicate that it operates on a collection rather than a single item (Tasks instead of Task, for instance).

I was not, however, aware that I was doing Saxon genitive programming; I'll add that to my resume immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to make your function names several words long to distinguish them from each other, you are probably failing in the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) so none of your suggested options will help.

I write OO code, mainly in OO languages, so to verify the priority of a task you'd have `task.verifyPriority()`, though usually just have `task.verify()` as the public method.

Verifying the priority may involve other logic - say the priority can only be 7 if the task's owner is Bob. Setting the owner of one of Bob's priority 7 tasks to Anna would make it inconsistent, but would you have `verifyOwner()` to be called when you change the owner as well as `verifyPriority()` for when you change the priority, even if they had the same logic?

I've found that making APIs less specific to the detail of the implementation leads to more malleable code.

In non-OO languages I usually use `<library>_<Noun>_<Verb>` so `tman_task_verify ( task_t* self )` to verify the task object in the task manager library to verify itself.

Comment: This answer is suggesting an alternative naming, but does not provide an answer to the question by OP.

Comment: @clapas I think this is a valid answer. If the author thinks that an alternative would better suit than the two options presented in the question.

Comment: @clapas the question "What do you call your functions ..,. ?" is explicitly answered. Stackoverflow is not a multiple choice exam.

Comment: @PeteKirkham please don't omit the significant part: "What do you call your functions when names that contain a saxon genitive..."

Comment: @clapas as stated in the answer, if you need to use then you already have another problem with your design, so solve that problem first. Choosing one of three bad options is a bad answer to the question. There is only so much worth discussing in a ten year old question, you are free to downvote or upvote another answer or whatever, but you seem to be the only person complaining in the last ten years, so I'm not going to change the answer further.

Answer (score 2):

This old question drew my attention when searching for some subtleties of the Saxon Genitive. According to [Wall Street English](https://www.wallstreetenglish.com/blog/english-possessives-the-saxon-genitive/) the Saxone Genitive is used to describe possesion:

> The Saxon Genitive substitutes the word ‘of’ to show possession. It’s
> used mainly to refer to things owned by people, but it can also be
> used with animals, organizations and even some time expressions. To
> create the saxon genitive we add ‘s to a name. For example:
>
> This is John’s car. = This is the car of John.

Further down on the same page we find the following:

> #### When not to use the Saxon Genitive
>
> We don’t normally use the saxon
> genitive with objects. In this case we prefer ‘of’. For example:
>
> The door of the house. (NOT ‘The house’s door’.)
>
> The lid of the pen. (NOT ‘The pen’s lid’.)
>
> The end of the road. (NOT ‘The road’s end’.)
>
> Generally speaking, if you’re not sure whether or not to use the saxon
> genitive, it’s safer to use ‘of’.

This means we wouldn't say **task's priority** or **action's delay**. Therefore the first option should be eliminated altogether.

The third option is grammatically correct, but sounds something unwieldy.

The second option uses [compound nouns](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/compound-nouns/). As explained on that page, there are many possibilities to build a compound noun, the first given is a combination of *noun + noun*:

> - bedroom
> - water tank
> - motorcycle
> - printer cartridge

We can also think of other examples used in computer programming, like: status code, design pattern, syntax error, etc.

The second option is thus the way to go.

Since I'm very pedantic about naming conventions I wanted to share my findings and further support the previous answers.